# Can't sort 3 floating point numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am wring program that sorts three integers. But I am not getting result for the input {1,3,2}. Probably some logic mistake in the 4th if statement.

The numbers are taken as input.

// program to sorting 3 double.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input the numbers for sorting");

        double num1 = in.nextDouble();
        double num2 = in.nextDouble();
        double num3 = in.nextDouble();

        double a = 0;
        double b = 0;
        double c = 0;

        if ((num1 > num2) && (num2 > num3)) {
            a = num1;
            b = num2;
            c = num3;
        }
        if ((num1 > num2) && (num3 > num2)) {
            a = num1;
            b = num3;
            c = num2;
        }

        if ((num2 > num1) && (num1 > num3)) {
            a = num2;
            b = num1;
            c = num3;
        }

        if ((num2 > num1) && (num3 > num1)) {
            a = num2;
            b = num3;
            c = num1;
        }

        if ((num3 > num1) && (num1 > num2)) {
            a = num3;
            b = num1;
            c = num2;
        }

        if ((num3 > num1) && (num2 > num1)) {
            a = num3;
            b = num2;
            c = num1;
        }
        System.out.println(" The numbers are in" + c + "< " + b + "< " + a);

    }
}
```

Comment: What if requirement changes and you should sort 4 numbers? Will create 24 if statements? Think about generic approach.

Comment: *"Probably some logic mistake in the 4th if statement."* - Or somewhere.  Hint: use a debugger.  If you don't know how, now is a good time to learn.

Comment: Just a detail, what if the user enters the same number twice? I think I’d use `>=` in the comparisons and `<=` in the printout instead of `<` and `>`.

Comment: This condition is insufficient: `(num1 > num2) && (num3 > num2)`. you now now that `num1` and `num3` are both greater than `num2`, but you don’t know which one is greatest.

Comment: There are a couple of more insufficient conditions like the one I mentioned. Go find. I have not thought it through, but the problem you report may be caused by one of there.

Comment: When asking for debugging help, always also give actual observed output (“not getting result” is a bit too vague).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with an array, you may use the `Arrays.sort()` method:

```
    double[] numbers = new double[] { num1, num2, num3 };
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println("The numbers are " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Given input `1 3 2` this prints `The numbers are [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with arrays. Example :

```
class DoubleSorter {
    public double[] sorted;
    public boolean[] deleted;
    public int array_position=0;
    public int element_to_delete=0;
    public DoubleSorter() {
    }
    public void self_calling_sorter(double[] numbers) {
        double bestnum=0;
        boolean finished=true;
        for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
             if (deleted[i] == false) {
                 if (finished==true) { //First set to bestnum
                     bestnum=numbers[i];
                     element_to_delete=i;
                     finished=false;
                 }
                 else {
                     if (numbers[i] >= bestnum) {
                         bestnum=numbers[i];
                         element_to_delete=i;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         deleted[element_to_delete]=true;
         if (finished==false) {
             sorted[array_position]=bestnum;
             array_position++;
             self_calling_sorter(numbers);
         }
    }

    public double[] sort(double[] numbers) {
        sorted=new double[numbers.length];
        deleted=new boolean[numbers.length];
        for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
             deleted[i]=false;
        }
        self_calling_sorter(numbers);
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

This function takes an array, looks for the biggest element, writes it down, sets it to null, calls itself, looks for the biggest element, excludes the taken, because they were set to null, writes the biggest number again...

Example of how it works :

```
numbers={1,3,2};
result={null,null,null};
```

First sorting :

```
result={3,null,null};
numbers={1,null,2};
```

Second sorting :

```
result={3,2,null};
numbers={1,null,null};
```

Third sorting :

```
result={3,2,1};
numbers={null,null,null};
```

A fourt sorting isnt executed because it notices that bestnum is null because it couldnt be set.

This function is more flexible and can sort a almost infinite amount of numbers much easier.

And here is how I would integrate it in your code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleSorter sorter=new DoubleSorter();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to sort ?");
        int count = in.nextInt();
        double[] numbers=new double[count];
        for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
             System.out.println("Number "+Integer.toString(i));
             numbers[i]=in.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("The sorted list is : "+Arrays.toString(sorter.sort(numbers)));
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

I saw this and realized that you'd probably like to sort them the other way round.

> ```
> System.out.println(" The numbers are in" + c + "< " + b + "< " + a);
> ```

Then you'll only have to change this :

```
if (numbers[i] >= bestnum) {
    bestnum=numbers[i];
    element_to_delete=i;
}
```

to this :

```
if (numbers[i] <= bestnum) {
    bestnum=numbers[i];
    element_to_delete=i;
}
```

Comment: I cannot compile your `DoubleSorter` class. For example, you cannot do `double bestnum=null;`. A Java `double` cannot be `null` (a `Double` (with capital D) can).

Comment: I'm sorry, I always use doubles that are null in arrays.

Comment: Probably `double bestnum;` sets it by default to zero ?

Comment: Edited it. Should compile.

Comment: Have you tried? I still get “The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null” at the line `if (numbers[i] != null) {`.

Comment: Im so sorry, but now I fixed it. Copy the new sorter class. It will work.

Comment: Not giving up, nice. It’s not the most elegant of sorting algorithms, but I believe it works now. I gave your code a few challenges and it sorted my numbers correctly each time.

Comment: I know its not the most elegant, but how else to do easily ?

Comment: My algorithm is almost efficient:It takes the list, determines the biggest number, now does this with the rest, and so on. I dont know an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133340/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-user7185318).